# How to load javascript in child htmls of ng-view

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am new to angular. I want to know how to load javascript for html inside ng-view.

I have seen answers like add jquery. Could you help me what exactly is to add and in which file.

My files are given below

```html
<!Doctype HTML>
<html ng-app="adminHomeApp" style="height: 100%;">
<head>

<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="js/admin/adminHomeApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height:100%">
<table width="100%" border="1" height="80%">
<tr height="10%">
 <td width="100%" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><h1>Admin Home</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr height="90%" valign="top">
 <td width="10%" ng-include="'/views/admin/index.html'"></td>
 <td width="90%" valign="middle" align="center">
  <table width="100%" height="100%">
   <tr width="100%" height="100%">
    <td align="center" valign="middle"><div ng-view /></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
//Define an angular module for our app
var adminHomeApp = angular.module('adminHomeApp', ['ngRoute']);

adminHomeApp.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when('/addCategory', {
  templateUrl : '/views/admin/addCategory.html',
 });
} ]);
```

```js
<script src="bower_components/jqlite/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/admin/category/categoryApp.js"></script>
<table border="1" ng-controller="CategoryController">
<tr>
 <td>Category Name</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="category.name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Parent</td>
 <td>
  <select ng-model="category" ng-options="category.name for category in categories"></select>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2"><button type="button">Add</button></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

```js
adminHomeApp.controller('CategoryController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.categories = [
                   {name:'--Select One--'},    
                   {name:'cat1'},
                   {name:'cat2'}                   
                 ];
  $scope.category = $scope.categories[0]; 
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done in correct way, but your partials are inside `'/views/admin/addCategory.html'`

so you need to point the js files from there

try

```
<script src="../bower_components/jqlite/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/admin/category/categoryApp.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Hareesh. I tried it. But it didn't work.

I am using node in the backend and I have set
app.use(express.static('public'))

So all static files are directly related to the public folder as the root